# Different services on different ports in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding

I'm in a situation where I want to use WCF to expose two different interfaces:

- Internal (IPC communication)
- External (Http REST)

The external interface shouldn't be able to see or use the internal interface so what I was thinking about were to host the two services on different ports e.g. (8000 for internal and 8001 for external) and then block all external communication on port 8000.

Moreover, I tried fiddling around with using named pipes for IPC communication, and I ran into an issue. If the unexpected situation occurs, that the service crashes or goes offline the client would also have to be restarted to be able to establish the communication with the service via the named pipes. Is this normal behavior and can it be avoided?

I have the following code so far:

```
// Service Host
var host = new ServiceHost(serviceContract, new Uri(_address));
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true });
var behaviour = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>();
behaviour.InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single;

// Local Endpoint
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ILocalServiceContract), new BasicHttpBinding(), "Local");
host.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");

// External Endpoint
var webHttpBidning = new WebHttpBinding { TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed };
var externalEndPoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IExternalServiceContract), webHttpBidning, "External");
externalEndPoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
```

They are currently both hosted on the same port which I want to avoid, I'm fairly new to WCF and I could really use some guidance for best practice and what I'm doing wrong. As mentioned earlier the 'BasicHttpBinding' could maybe be replaced with a named pipe if my issue can be resolved.

Looking forward to hear to the experts and if you need any clearification feel free to ask :)

Comment: `that the service crashes or goes offline the client would also have to be restarted to be able to establish the communication with the service via the named pipes.` this means you're not handling faults correctly. you need to destroy the proxy and create a new one to re-establish the connection. That's why restarting the client solves it, since it's a new instance of the proxy. Once a proxy faults, it can never be used again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I expose the named pipe binding via MEX, how do I destroy the proxy and do I have to do it each time? A code example or link would be really nice :)

Comment: https://github.com/rmandvikar/WcfServiceClientHelper is great for managing the proxy instantiation for you

Comment: Regarding another person's commentary, strong typed WCF configuration is absolutely the correct choice. It's the only way Juval Lowy ever intended for it to be used. Microsoft forced xml on top of it for no reason at all, only because it was during the yester years of `xml config is the bees knees`  **when *everything* needed moar xml.** Everything about WCF is supposed to be **convention over configuration** but you'd never know that from how microsoft framed the dialog on it which is an utter travesty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue with the following code on server. On the clients which communicate with the server via named pipes, I used "`WcfClientProxyGenerator`" library to generate fault tolerant client proxies.

```
_namedPipeAddress = "net.pipe://localhost/";
_httpAddress = "http://localhost:8000";

var host = new ServiceHost(serviceContract, new Uri(_namedPipeAddress), new Uri(_httpAddress));

host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { });

var behaviour = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>();
behaviour.InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single;
behaviour.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;

// Local Endpoint
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ILocalServiceContract), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "Local");
host.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexNamedPipeBinding(), "mex");

//// External Endpoint
var webHttpBidning = new WebHttpBinding { TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed };
var externalEndPoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IExternalServiceContract), webHttpBidning, new Uri(_httpAddress));
externalEndPoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
```

For further improvements to this solution feel free to comment :)